# React-Native get key of Listitem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, key, listitem, native-base

so i'm trying to get the key of a ListItem, generated in a loop for, but i get a undefined value.

```
<ListItem id={i} key = {i} button onPress={() => alert(this.key)}>
```

If someone can help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `key`. It is a [special string attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). Rather use the `i` variable because in your case it is the `key`.

```
<ListItem id={i} key = {i} button onPress={() => alert(i)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, look the code :

```
for(var i = 0; i< data.service.length; i++ )
    {
    listArr.push(
        <ListItem key={i} button onPress={(key) => this.ChangeHome(key) }>
          <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: data.service[i].logo }} />
          <Body>
          <Text>{data.service[i].id}</Text>
            <Text>{data.service[i].title}</Text>
            <Text note>{data.service[i].info}</Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>

    );
}
```

As you can see if I put only the i, the alert will show 2 ( the end of the loop for) instead the id of the list item ( 0 or 1 ) :/